# Fragment Activity Backstack

Tags: android

I am having problems with my backstack. I have a main activity that launches a FragmentActivity A which then starts an Activity B.  When i call finish() on B it goes back to the main activity not A.  I debugged it and A is not being destroyed until finish() is called on B but A is being skipped over.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. Read fragment lifecycle

Comment: I have read that.. Not sure how that helps me.. Because i am going Activity -> FragmentActivity -> Activity. Adding the fragment to the backstack doesn't help me here.

Comment: Check the topic under **Handling the Fragment Lifecycle**.  A fragment is placed into a back stack managed by the host activity. What's happening when you press back button is correct.

Comment: Its not. I have activities Main, A , B.  The call order goes like this Main -> A -> B. The fragment is attached to A. But when i press back on B it goes to Main skipping over A. So the back stack looks like this B-> Main. I want it to do this B->A->Main

Comment: MainActivity - FragmentActivityA -Activity B. Is this the sequence?.

Comment: yes that is the sequence

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28683/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user1634451)